# Xpages - How do I ensure submitted values are unique

Tags: xpages

This is driving me nuts!
I have an xPage form that is available for Anonymous users. I want to ensure that one of the values is unique throughtout the database so have a validation of on the field - but this is where is gets tricky - as the user does not have access to the data in the database this validation does not work.

@IsMember(value, @DbColumn("","Names",1))

I have tried to write an agent that has agent signer privileges to do the validation but can not get this to work and I think agent.runWithDocumentContext(doc); requires the agent to run as the WebUser

Any hints?
Cheers
Tim

Comment: Did you try saving session as signer?  It should look something like this: sessionAsSigner.getCurrentDatabase().  This way it looks up as the signers ID and not the current users.

Comment: @IsMember(value, @DbColumn("", "Names", 1)) will return true if the value _already exists_. You should validate to _true_ if they _don't_ already exist (making them unique/new), so changing to use @IsNotMember(... makes more sense to me.

Comment: OK sorry about my poor logic Eric - I got this working when I was signed in as me - but when I logged in as a public user who does not have access to the other docs in the database the dbcolumn returns no values so the validation does not work

Comment: SessionAsSigner seems to be on the right track.....var curDB:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(session.getServerName(),session.getCurrentDatabase().getFilePath()); 
var compInput = getComponent("ShortName");
var input:string = profileDoc.getItemValue("ShortName");
var curDBview:NotesView = curDB.getView("(Shortnames)"); 
var vc:NotesViewEntryCollection = curDBview.getAllEntriesByKey(String(input),true);
getComponent("CompanyName").setValue(vc.getCount())

Comment: Just a thought - is that value sensitive? Because by trial/error even anonymous user can get an idea what values are there...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run SSJS @Formulas as another user.

You need to use `sessionAsSigner`. One caveat with that, is that you cannot use `sessionAsSigner.getCurrentDatabase()` - that function returns the current user's current database (or did in previous versions, I'm not aware of any amendment to that functionality). Instead you need to use `sessionAsSigner.getDatabase()`, passing in the server and filepath. From there you can access the view, try `getEntryByKey(myKey, true)` and check whether the result is `null`. If it's not, it already exists in the view. But if the code runs on every save, make sure to check the document returned is not the one you're currently editing, so you'll need `getAllEntriesByKey()` instead, looping through to check for a document whose UNID doesn't match the current one.

It's a bit convoluted, which is why the latest release of OpenNTF Domino API includes `View.checkUnique(String, Document)` to the extended Domino `View` class (corresponding to the SSJS `NotesView` class), which does all of that checking automatically. But that requires the OpenNTF Domino API installed as a plugin on the server.

Comment: SessionAsSigner seems to be on the right track.....Trying to debug this by putting output in to CompanyName
vc.getCount() gives me the correct number when I hardcode entry into getAllEntriesByKey but when I try to use the value from the ShortName field it comes up with zero

Comment: var curDB:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(session.getServerName(),session.getCurrentDatabase()‌​.getFilePath()); 
var compInput = getComponent("ShortName"); 
var input:string = profileDoc.getItemValue("ShortName"); 
var curDBview:NotesView = curDB.getView("(Shortnames)"); 
var vc:NotesViewEntryCollection = curDBview.getAllEntriesByKey(String(input),true); 
getComponent("CompanyName").setValue(vc.getCount())